# Android- How to store and retrieve a SecretKey object locally and retrieve it

Tags: android, encryption, cryptography, secret-key

I am creating an app which should allow the encryption of audio files. I am creating a SecretKey object and using it to encrypt and decrypt files. It all works ok, but now I need a way to store the SecretKey object locally so that when the app is opened again, it can be used to decrypt data.

I have attempted several methods including the following:

```
final byte[] filesBytes = encodeFile(mySecretKey, stringToSave);
SharedPreferences settings = context.getSharedPreferences(KEY_PREFS, 0);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
editor.putString("cryptoKey", Arrays.toString(filesBytes));
```

To retrieve the data, I am attempting the following:

```
SharedPreferences settings = context.getSharedPreferences(KEY_PREFS, 0);
    String stringArray = settings.getString("cryptoKey", null);

    if (stringArray != null) {
        String[] split = stringArray.substring(1, stringArray.length() - 1).split(", ");
        byte[] array = new byte[split.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
            array[i] = Byte.parseByte(split[i]);
        }
        localSecretKey = new SecretKeySpec(array, "AES");
    }
```

I have also looked at posts such as: [How to store secretKey in KeyStore and retrieve it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24231213/how-to-store-secretkey-in-keystore-and-retrieve-it) which haven't helped.

What I need to know is, How can I store the SecretKey object locally so I can retrieve it later on when the app is reopened?

Comment: You missed to point out what you actual problem is. Please edit your question and improve it.

Comment: Storing keys in key stores seem like a good solution in general, why didn't that help you?

Comment: I have edited the question. My issue is that I need to know how to store the SecretKey object locally

Comment: Does `mySecretKey.getEncoded()` work for you?